# How to assign dictionary value to dataframe by key matching to the name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

dataframe:

```
Name  class  section
A      5        c
B      3        a
C      4        b
```

Dictionary:

```
dict={A:['Singing','dancing','Drawing'],C:['Gamming','Painting'],D:['Football','Basketball']}
```

Expected output:

```
Name  Class  Section  Hobby
A      5      c       Singing
                      dancing
                      Drawing
B      3      a      
C      4      b       Gaming
                      Painting
D                     Football
                      Basketball
```

I need to combine the dataframe and dictionary based on matching the names and, in some cases dataframe will not be having that name in that case I need to add extra row in dataframe, and I need to do this in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First dont use `dict` for dictionary variable, because python code name.

For add missing values form keys in dictionary use [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), then for new column use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and then [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
df = df.set_index('Name')

df = df.reindex(df.index.union(d.keys(), sort=False)).rename_axis('Name').reset_index()

df['Hobby'] = df['Name'].map(d)
df = df.explode('Hobby')
print (df)
  Name  class section       Hobby
0    A    5.0       c     Singing
0    A    5.0       c     dancing
0    A    5.0       c     Drawing
1    B    3.0       a         NaN
2    C    4.0       b     Gamming
2    C    4.0       b    Painting
3    D    NaN     NaN    Football
3    D    NaN     NaN  Basketball
```

Last if need duplicated set to empty strings and also replace NaNs :

```
df.loc[df.index.duplicated(), ['Name','class','section']] = ''
df = df.fillna('').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  Name class section       Hobby
0    A     5       c     Singing
1                        dancing
2                        Drawing
3    B     3       a            
4    C     4       b     Gamming
5                       Painting
6    D                  Football
7                     Basketball
```